# opengl - displayed image sheared

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to use OpenGL to display images read from disk by Microsoft `CImage` library.

The image now can be roughly seen in the window, but clearly there are something wrong. The image is gray, and it's sheared. I can't figure out where is the problem because every pixel should be corresponding to the its slot in `_data`.

OpenGL image:
[image: opengl image]

Original image:
[image: original image]

Below is my code:

```
int _w = 300;
int _h = 300;
GLubyte ***_data;

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, _w, 0.0, _h);
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
    glDrawPixels(_w, _h, GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CImage img_handler;
    img_handler.Load(_T("bg.jpg"));
    _w = img_handler.GetWidth();
    _h = img_handler.GetHeight();

    COLORREF pixel;
    _data = new GLubyte**[_h];

    for (int y = 0; y < _h; y++) {
        _data[_h-y-1] = new GLubyte*[_w];
        for (int x = 0; x < _w; x++) {
            pixel = img_handler.GetPixel(x, y);

            _data[_h-y-1][x] = new GLubyte[3];
            _data[_h-y][x][0] = (GLubyte)GetRValue(pixel);
            _data[_h-y][x][1] = (GLubyte)GetGValue(pixel);
            _data[_h-y][x][2] = (GLubyte)GetBValue(pixel);
        }
    }

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH/*enable depth buffer*/);
    glutInitWindowSize(_w, _h);
    glutCreateWindow("test");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this OpenGL doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) on glDrawPixels (emphasis added):

> width x height pixels are read from memory, starting at location data. By default, these pixels are taken from adjacent memory locations, except that after all width pixels are read, **the read pointer is advanced to the next four-byte boundary**.  The four-byte row alignment is specified by glPixelStore with argument GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, and it can be set to one, two, four, or eight bytes.

Note that your colors are defined as 3 `GLuint` values - only 3 bytes!  Each row of pixels contains `3 * 897 = 2691` bytes.  The next multiple of 4 after `2691` is `2692` and so the way `glDrawPixels` is defined, GL skips one byte after each row.  This is why the image is sheared and why it appears gray (if you zoom in, you'll see that it is not gray, but rather every third row has the correct colors and the ones in between are hue shifted by 120 degrees).

The way to fix this is to make a `glPixelStore` call ahead of the `glDrawPixels` call.  It's sufficient to change

```
glDrawPixels(_w, _h, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
```

to

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glDrawPixels(_w, _h, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
```

---

Also, the code inside your `for` loop is not correct.  `_h-y` should be `_h-y-1` so that when `y=0` you do not write outside of the array's bounds and similarly when `y=_h-1` you write to the `0`th index of the array.

Also, do look into dynamic memory allocation, instead of allocating an array of static size.  This will make your code less prone to access violations i.e. reading / writing memory that does not in fact belong to you, leading to crashes and other problems.

Comment: That one line of code works like magic! I tried to use dynamically allocated array to store those bytes, but the program crashes, so I use fixed size for debugging the shearing issue. I've edited part of the code to use dynamic allocation. Would you mind take some time to look at it?

Comment: I tried to debug the code in VS, but it seems that `_data = new GLubyte**[_h];` doesn't successfully allocate memory, but I don't know why...

Comment: @AccM You'll have to do `GLubyte *_data = new GLubyte[_h * _w * 3];` so that the memory will be contiguous - and then change your for loop to `_data[3 * ((_h - 1 - y) * _w + x)] = (GLubyte)GetRValue(pixel);` and likewise for the G and B values.